# Mongo beginner's questions

Tags: mongodb

I've been reading the mongo manual and playing with it and i'm really
loving it so far , i just have a few questions that i can't seem to
get an answer from the documentation :

1. 1.8 Introduced incremental map reducing , from what i understand by
   incremental mongo will give me the option to effect the latest map/
   reduce output in several ways , my question is whether the new map/
   reduce i just ran will iterate over all of the data or just the delta
   from the last map/reduce ?
2. As a follow to the last question what is the atomic level of map/
   reduce ? i understand there is none but is there a way to find whether
   a certain document participated in the mapping or what was his
   revision at the time by an out of the box solution ?
3. Would u recommend running 2 replicaes on one amazon micro instance
   (i'm aware this is not the way to go and the redundancy ...) this is
   for a poc purposes mainly , i want to test the latency of the replica
   and to get a feeling for the enviroument ? are there any better
   hosting solutions for mongo (better bang per buck) ?
4. anyone here know of a published article that has use case of
   intensive writes , sharding and periodic map reduces ? those are my
   reasons for going with mongo
5. is there a way to include external data inside the map reduce
   functions , e.g. : i have a geo redis database with a js api i want to
   hit in my reducing ?

Thanks guys !

Comment: put these into separate questions

Answer (score 0):

Regarding #1,2,5: I don't want to RTFM you, but you honestly need to read the [MongoDB Map/Reduce pages](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce) to truly understand it.

Regarding #3: You probably won't get any value over running multiple instances on the same AWS Micro instance.  Other than testing out how to set up mongod, mongos, replication, sharding, etc, there's very little value in doing so on the same machine; you might as well do that on your local machine.  (Unless you want separate instances to behave differently regarding sharding & replication, say a staging environment, but even that seems like bad practice hosting production and staging on the same machine...)

Regarding #4: There are many presentations on the web (videos and slides) about companies having selected to use MongoDB for these reasons.  One specific company which has done so is FourSquare.  Checking out [10gen's Presentations page](http://www.10gen.com/presentations) is a fine place to start.

Hope that this helps.